# how can i separate words stuck together?

Tags: php

I have a lot of files which are named poorly

```
videoofmegoingtoschool.avi
```

is there a library or some algorithm out there that will separate it properly ?

```
video of me going to school.avi
```

Comment: You must be one of the few people who hasn't adopted the *brilliant* idea of spaces in file names.

Comment: pavium: personally I tokenise my filenames in the following form: `silkys THE FINAL FRONTIER video.avi`. (*giggles at his hilarious joke*).

Comment: I don't actually *like* spaces in filenames, but I concede this is one time they would have been useful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195010/how-can-i-split-multiple-joined-words

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's anything out there. I could envision a program that uses a dictionary of words and selects the shortest word that matches left to right and then if it cannot find a second word it fails back to search for the next largest word and so on. (backtracking if necessary)  However this could come up with false positives and negatives.  Sounds like a fun problem to tackle!

Comment: if said problem is tackled, it should be done in a nice abstract fashion so that we have an api to work with if we want to do something OTHER than parse filenames.

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed several times before here on SO, unfortunately [I can only find one link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230373/word-separating-algorithm) now.

**EDIT - More Links:**

- [How to sort all possible words out of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538589/how-to-sort-all-possible-words-out-of-a-string)
- [How can I split multiple joined words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195010/how-can-i-split-multiple-joined-words) (this one is a fun read)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect not. It's even an interesting problem to solve, because you must determine the most 'likely' way to split, and splitting at certain points will affect future splits. A fun project for someone in their spare time, but in the real world, you'll need to do it manually :)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a dictionary, and t(str) means that str is a valid word or group of words,
t(str) = sum_over_i(t(str[0,i]) && t(str[i+1, length])
that is, to check if a groupofwords forms a valid group-of-words, add a space after the first letter and see if you can still form words with both halves; if that doesn't work, try after the second letter, then the third...

with dynamic programming, this can be done in O(n^2) time!

[Edit]  People don't like my answer.  Perhaps some pseudo-code.

```
function IsValidString(x)
    if(x is one letter, not 'a' or 'i')
        return false
    if(x is a dictionary word)
        return true
    for i from 0 to x.length-2
        if( IsValidString(x[0,i]) and IsValidString(x[i+1, x.length-1]) )
            return true
    return false
```

Here, IsValidString returns true if there is a way to break up the string into individual, valid words, and false otherwise.  It is not hard to see how you could keep track of which values of *i* (space placement) made the string valid.

Comment: oh yeah t(str) is immediately true if str is in the dictionary, and false if str is one-letter long and not 'a' or 'i'

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you may have:
/usr/share/dict/american-english

---

You can try creating a word 1 letter at a time (from the left), then seeing if it exists as a whole in that dict file.  Then save that token as a separate word.