# R spell checker / tokenizer

Tags: python, r

I'm not sure if R is the right place to try this or not but here's my situation.  I have a character vector full of strings.

```
id    Words
 1    'The'
 2    'victory'
 3    'wasgreat'
...   ...
```

The original data had some encoding problems and some of the strings are concatenizations of several words:

```
 (ie 'My name is' -> 'Mynameis').
```

I need to leave the correct words alone and get the misspelled concatenizations separated into their correct substrings.

I'm curious if there's any setup in R to handle this type of problem.  I think that there are several programs in python that would handle this much better but my python skills are substantially weaker (bordering on non-existent).  However, I'd be willing to consider it as an alternative.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897214/breaking-a-string-into-individual-wordspython

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most recent issue of the [R Journal](http://journal.r-project.org) has an [article by Hornik and Murdoch on R for spell-checking](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-2/RJournal_2011-2_Hornik+Murdoch.pdf) which, recursion to the rescue, they apply to the R sources themselves.

Comment: I've been all day trying to figure out how to make aspell to work with custom dictionaries on Windows 7 x64. Tried the **saveRDS()** function and the **aspell_write_personal_dictionary_file()** function. With the former I receive this error **"The word "UTF-8" is invalid. The character '-' may not appear at the middle of a word."** and a warning. With the later **aspell** can't find my custom dictionary. Any idea about how to attack this?